# Ant how disable print target name for foreach target

Tags: ant, foreach, target

I have code below:

```
... 
<foreach target="each-time-target" param="file">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/target" casesensitive="yes">
        <include name="libs/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</foreach>
...
```

When I execute it I see in output

```
each-time-target:

each-time-target:

each-time-target:

....
```

Is there exists some option to disable target name printing for specific targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-emacs` commandline option, f.e.

```
ant -emacs -f foobar.xml
```

see [Ant Manual Options](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options) for details